# Spark cluster OutOfMemoryError with way more memory then needed

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks

I have a spark cluster with a 28gb driver and 8x 56gb workers.  I am attempting to process a 4gb file.  I can successfully process this file without the use of spark on my 16gb of memory on my own laptop so there is no memory leak causing the full 56gb to be used, it can also process smaller sample files just fine.  I am submitting this job with azure databricks (though this should be irrelevant).  All configurations on my spark cluster are default.

Code in question

```
  var ou = distData.map(s => ProcessObj.exec(s.toString) ).collect
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferOutputStream.write(ByteBufferOutputStream.scala:41)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1853)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:709)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(SerializableBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(SerializableBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1359)
at org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer.writeObject(SerializableBuffer.scala:47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage.serialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:528)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$launchTasks$1.apply(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$launchTasks$1.apply(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:293)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
```

Update:

Attempted with the following spark configuration and still getting out of memory error:

```
spark.executor.memory 40g
spark.driver.memory 20g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spark.driver.memory` by default is 1GB. It could be different for preconfigured Spark on Azure, but it still seems to be less than amount of data you are trying to process.

Then you are calling for collect() on DataFrame, result content would be transferred into driver host, so it should be capable of storing in memory of driver process, which is a JVM process with pre-set amount of available memory (it could not be resized to all host memory in general).

Comment: Thanks @gemelen.  I added `spark.executor.memory 40g` and`spark.driver.memory 20g` configurations to the cluster just incase, restarted, and ran the job again, however still getting the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: There are two directions:

1. use Spark as it suggested to be used - process your file in a distributed manner and store result on distributed storage (HDFS or object storage), so no data would hit driver.

2. investigate how much memory you really need - you can start with observing memory metrics on Storage page of Spark application UI (or using other profiling tools like one for JVM profiling).

Comment: Okay, I will look into 1, because that is exactly what I am trying to do.  The function processes a single line and outputs a new line into a file on hdfs.  However, at the moment I am collecting the outputs then writing to the output file in hdfs in a later part of the script because I couldn't figure out how to do it on the cluster.  I will look into that approach more then, thanks!

Comment: @jayjay93 it'd be nice from you then to accept answer as satisfactory